# Cannot access memory at address

Tags: c, pointers

```
 char* dayOfProgrammer(int year) {
 char s[15];
if (year >= 1700 && year < 1918) {
if (year % 4 == 0) {
    strcpy(s,"12.09.");
  strcat(s,(char*)(intptr_t)year);
} else {
    strcpy(s,"13.09.");
  strcat(s,(char*)(intptr_t)year);
}
}
if (year >1918 && year < 2700) {
    if(year%400==0 || (year%4==0 && year%100!=0)){
        strcpy(s,"12.09.");
      strcat(s,(char*)(intptr_t)year);
    }else{
        strcpy(s,"13.09.");
      strcat(s,(char*)(intptr_t)year);
    }
}
if(year==1918){
    strcpy(s,"26.09.");
  strcat(s,(char*)(intptr_t)year);
    }  return s;    }
```

I have tried ever thing to take output but its showing error

```
 0x00007fc49d95dc85 in __strcpy_chk (dest=0x7ffed426cc9f "", 
src=0x7e1 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x7e1>, destlen=15)
at strcpy_chk.c:28
```

my task is to add pointer char and number like, ("12.09."+some number).

If you have any method then please suggest.
I have try memory alloaction also but it also didn't work.
I have found very diffculties in joining to pointer string and int

Comment: `strcat(s,(char*)(intptr_t)year);` What do you think is this doing?

Comment: You did not specify, in a code comment, what the code is supposed to achieve. You did not tell in your post: Please edit your post and describe what you are trying to get done.

Comment: `strcat(s,(char*)(intptr_t)year);` invokes *Undefined Behavior*. `year` is not a *nul-terminated* string which likely causes `strcat` to go screaming off across your function stack looking for the first *nul-byte* which is equally likely well beyond the bound of `s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strcpy(s,"12.09.");
strcat(s,(char*)(intptr_t)year);
```

This is most likely not doing what you think it does. You cast the year to an address and try to access it which in nearly every case invokes undefined behavior. You should take a look at the `snprintf` function which is suitable for this task:

```
snprintf(s, sizeof s, "12.09.%d", year);
```

The next problem is that you are trying to return a local array which also leads to undefined behavior. You have to either make it `static` or allocate it with `malloc`.

Comment: i used malloc and static but didn't work. i used (intptr_t) because size of string and int are different. and i have to return the "s" so i cant use snprint.